# Confusion regarding definition of $\textbf a^{\langle t\rangle}$ in cs-math paper

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, limits, normed-spaces

I am confused by pages 5 and 6 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.07630.pdf) regarding the EM algorithm for mixtures of two Gaussians. In particular I am confused whether $\textbf a^{\langle t \rangle}=\frac{\mu_1^{{\langle t \rangle}}+\mu_2^{{\langle t \rangle}}}{2}$ or $\textbf a^{\langle t \rangle}=\frac{\mu_1^{{\langle t \rangle}}+\mu_2^{{\langle t \rangle}}}{2}-\frac{\mu_1^{{*}}+\mu_2^{{*}}}{2}$ (as defined in the paper). Unless I'm not understanding, the authors seem to be switching back and forth between these two definitions in page 6, preventing me from reading the page coherently. I have been pondering this for days and this is one of the first math papers I'm reading in detail, so it'd be appreciated it someone with more experience in real analysis could let me know what's up. Thanks

Comment: They do not say that $\mathbf{a}^{\langle t \rangle}$ is equal to the first, only that it **converges** to that.  (Assuming the first should have upper *s instead of $\langle t \rangle$'s as on page 6.)

Comment: @Randall thanks for the comment, maybe I should be more specific. In page 6, "By combining the two inequalities from Theorem 3, we conclude" (with t large enough) $\| \textbf a^{\langle t+1 \rangle}\|^2\le 0$, meaning $\frac{\mu_1^{\langle t\rangle}+\mu_2^{\langle t \rangle}}{2}-\frac{\mu_1^{*}+\mu_2^{*}}{2}\rightarrow 0$ or $\frac{\mu_1^{\langle t\rangle}+\mu_2^{\langle t \rangle}}{2} \rightarrow \frac{\mu_1^{*}+\mu_2^{*}}{2}$. But then it says "the reparameterized iterates converge at a linear rate to $\frac{\mu_1^{*}+\mu_2^{*}}{2}$", not 0?

Comment: And then Theorem 5 says $(\textbf a^{\langle t \rangle }, \textbf b ^{\langle t \rangle})\rightarrow (0, 0)$ but again, Corollary 2 (which summarizes Theorem 3 and Theorem 5) says $\textbf a^{\langle t \rangle}\rightarrow \frac{\mu_1^{*}+\mu_2^{*}}{2}$...?